# Use OnItemClickListener in ListView inside ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to use `OnItemClickListener`method in a `ListView` but it's not being called because `ViewPager`intercepts touch events.

I've tried

```
mPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
```

in my `FragmentActivity`, and

```
lista.setDescendantFocusability(ListView.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

in my onCreate method in `ListFragment`but nothing happens. ("lista" is my `ListView`).

Here is `OnItemClickListener` method code:

```
lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(id.list);

lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //It's not being called
    }

});
```

Some days ago I used only `Activities`instead of `Fragments`(now I need them because of `ViewPager`) and code worked fine, so I think xml is not needed.

**EDIT** Add more code:

*FragmentActivity*

```
public class TabsFacturasActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] titles = { "VER FACTURAS", "VER CONSUMO", "INTRODUCIR LECTURA" };
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0
            return new FacturasFragment();
        ...
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        if (object instanceof FacturasFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof DetallesFacturaFragment)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }
}
```

*ListFragment*

```
public class FacturasFragment extends ListFragment {

private ListView lista;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_facturas, container, false);

        ...

        lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(id.list);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
            //It's not being called
        }

        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to use OnItemClickListenermethod in a ListView but it's not being called because ViewPagerintercepts touch events" -- that's rather unlikely. You can use all sorts of interactive widgets inside of a `ViewPager`, without problems.

Comment: The normal structure is to have the ViewPager in MainActivity, and then the ViewPager hosts different Fragment or Fragment Instances. The onItemClickListener should be set from the Fragment itself, not the Activity. There shouldn't be interference at all.

Comment: But if I initialise my `ListView`in my `Fragment`class, not in `FragmentActivity`how can I achieve that?

Comment: I've added more code to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue can be caused by listView items. If your listView items contains clickable views (buttons, check boxes etc.) your **OnItemClickListener** will not be called.

Comment: It's a custom row with two `TextView`, and without using `Fragment`, it works.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are using 'ListFragment' as a parent of your fragment. 'ListFragment' has it's own 'onListItemClick' method. Try to extend Fragment instead.

Comment: I now use `ListFragment` and its own `onListItemClick` method and it works. Thank you!